# Sencha Touch not smoothly

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I'm using Sencha Touch 2.3 - 2.4 to build android application.
I make a list with 30 item to make it have a scroll bar. 
I build the application by using this command

```
sencha app build native
```

When I install it to my android device. **The list scroll not smooth. It have many latency** but when i copy the source code to an webserver and access it through Google Chrome it very smooth.

It not only the list scroll. All CSS effects, web aminiation all have latency.

Does anybody have been encountered this problem ? I have tried to use Sencha Architect to generate it samples. But nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

Android versions 4.3 and below use the Android Browser in the WebView component which doesn't have very good support for CSS3. To use the Chrome browser for Android version 4.0 - 4.3+  try Crosswalk https://crosswalk-project.org

You can also use the Intel XDK to build your Sencha Touch app with Crosswalk https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools